# Udev hook to backup USB content not working, but script working

Tags: bash, usb, udev

I've included a rule script in /etc/udev/rules.d to automate backup my USB content in a folder when i plug it in.

```
student@student-VirtualBox:/etc/udev/rules.d$ cat 80-local.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="058f", RUN+="/home/student/psop/triggertools/bin/principal.sh"
```

Script principal.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file="/home/student/psop/logs"

first_script="/home/student/psop/triggertools/bin/trigger.sh"

echo Starting scrip ... > "$log_file"

bash "$first_script"
```

Script trigger.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file="/home/student/psop/logs"
backup_dir="/home/student/psop/backupdir"
mount_dir="/home/student/psop/mountdir"
usb_device="/dev/sdb1"


if [ ! -d "$backup_dir" ]
then
    mkdir -p "$backup_dir"
fi

sudo systemd-mount --no-block --automount=no --collect "$usb_device" "$mount_dir" >> "$log_file" 2>&1
sleep 5

echo "Continut folder de montare: " >> "$log_file"
ls "$mount_dir" >> "$log_file"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    sudo /usr/local/bin/backup "$mount_dir" "$backup_dir" >> "$log_file" 2>&1
    sleep 5
    sudo umount "$usb_device" >> "$log_file"
else
    echo "Eroare la montarea dispozitivului!" >> "$log_file" 2>&1
fi
```

If I type the script line by line in bash terminal the mount / backup will work fine and if i type `bash /home/student/psop/triggertools/bin/principal.sh` works fine too. But if i just plug the stick in it won't work fine, the mount will eventually fail and the copy won't occur, but it just creates the folders with mkdir. What i'm missing?

Comment: I never tried something like this, but there is for sure one difference: If you run the script in your terminal, it is executed under **your** user-id, but if the stick is plugged in and the script is triggered, it is most likely NOT executed under your user-id. What I would do is to run your trigger.sh with `-x` turned on, and save the stderr somewhere. Maybe you can see from this log what's going wrong.

Comment: and add a `echo USER=$USER` . Good luck.